# Troubleshoot installing NVM.

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am following these instructions:

https://keymetrics.io/2015/02/03/installing-node-js-and-io-js-with-nvm/

and running this curl request:

curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.23.2/install.sh | bash

It opens my bash_profile (not my bashrc?) and nothing changes. I then do not have the npm command available to me in my bash and there is no .nvm file in my home directory and node -v doesn't work. Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The NVM documentation says that the installation script will try to add the source line to your `~/.bash_profile`:

> The script clones the nvm repository to `~/.nvm` and adds the source line to your profile (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc` or `~/.profile`).

And probably you are loading your `~/.bashrc` when opening your terminal without a reference to the `~/.bash_profile` so you are not 'sourcing' the nvm script.

Try adding these lines to your `~/.bashrc` and restart your terminal:

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

(I'm assuming that `~/.nvm` is your NVM installation directory).

Extra: You can check [this link](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) to learn about the difference between `.bashrc` and `_bash_profile`